# INSERT не добавляет данные в базу данных

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Данный код добавляет запись в базу данных, это отображается в 'DataGridView'. Но, если отрыть саму базу данных, в ней не появляются добавленные строки. Через некоторое время или рестарте студии добавленные строки перестают отображаться и в 'DataGridView'. Как записать строки в саму базу данных, что бы они не пропадали?

```
SqlConnection connection;
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBases2.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

string query = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (@userName, @userAge)";

using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", tbName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userAge", tbAge.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что нужно делать commit транзакции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточните пожалуйста, что Вы используете в качестве базы данных. Поведение очень похоже на работу с локальной файловой базой типа Access или подобной...
Студия, при компиляции каждый раз копирует такую базу в выходной каталог (bin\Release или bin\Debug) переписывая внесенные Вами изменения и работает с ней там. Если это так, то лечится это в так: в "Обозревателе решений" щелкаете на базе правой кнопкой мыши и выбираете "Свойства". Меняете "Копировать в выходной каталог" на значение "Копировать, если новее". И смотреть измененные данные нужно в выходном каталоге. Надеюсь помог :)

Comment: Я использую локальную базу данных в приложении Windows Forms. Свойство на "Копировать, если новее" менял. Все равно не помогает.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строку using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) на просто SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

Comment: И мне кажется что у Вас инсерт не правильно написан...string query = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (@userName, @userAge)"; Должно быть string query = "INSERT INTO Users(ПолеUserName, ПолеUserAge) VALUES (@userName, @userAge)";

Comment: Интересно. Теперь новые записи появляются в таблице (в DataGridView) даже после перезапуска студии, но все равно не появляются в самой таблице в базе данных.

Comment: А Вы где смотрите? Смотреть надо в базе которая находится в выходном каталоге bin\Release или bin\Debug!

Comment: Файл формата .mdf?

Comment: Да. Вы чем его смотрите?

Comment: Я не знаю, чем его смотреть (

Comment: До этого я просматривал его прямо в студии

Comment: Так из чего Вы сделали вывод, что данные не появились в базе данных?

Comment: Обозреватель серверов/Database1.mdf/Таблицы/ПКМ по Users/показать таблицу данных

Comment: Если добавляешь данные "вручную" (через интерфейс студии), тогда они там отлично сохраняются "навсегда"

Comment: Еще раз. Файл базы прикрученный к проекту является как-бы эталонным что ли... Вы в нем производите добавление таблиц, полей и т.д......При компиляции и запуске проекта студия копирует этот файл в выходной каталог и работает с ним там. И все изменения данных происходит в файле который находится в выходном каталоге. Если в гриде данные есть, то они есть и в базе данных. Просто Вы смотрите не том файле.....

Comment: А как открыть этот фаил .mdf?

Comment: Правильно! Если Вы вносите данные через интерфейс студии Вы вносите изменения в "эталонный файл", он становится "новее" чем файл в выходном каталоге и копируется в выходной каталог вместе с внесенными Вами данными.

Comment: Ну через обозреватель серверов присоедините файл из выходного каталога например. Только потом не запутайтесь куда Вы вносите изменения структуры....

Comment: Спасибо, вроде теперь понятнее

Comment: Если потом эту программу запустит у себя другой пользователь, на другом ПК, у него так же создастся своя новая БД на основе эталонной?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Можете отплюсовать мой ответ :)

Comment: Нет. Вы распространяете программу копированием того, что у Вас в выходном каталоге. И пользователь спокойно работает с базой предоставленной Вами.